# Not getting mail from jenkins but in console output displaying build was success

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Executed Selenium scripts through jenkins

Below is the issue:

SendFailedException message: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError a1sm23590585pgn.51 - gsmtp

Changed in gmail setting also.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prPLZ.png)

Comment: Looks like authentication with gmail is failing - verify that the gmail password you are using is correct. I'd recommend using an app password https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en , as it's possible that your login is being denied on jenkins as it's requesting a CAPTCHA/2FA entry from the server, which the server obviously can't complete

Comment: Hi Peter, tried with using same password and app password also. but still getting same error.

Comment: To confirm - you are using the full gmail address as the username?

Comment: HI Peter, used full gmail address as 'testabc2016@gmail.com'

Comment: karthikashoka, can you confirm for me the port you have set?

Comment: hi peter, SMTP port set as 465